# How to pass a csv file in next request if only when a correlation gives not_found value (if we dnt see any values)

Tags: csv, jmeter, correlation

****Jmeter****. i have specific case where the correlation values will return empty,(valid scenario), to maintain the tps in the next call, i think, it we could use the csv file and pass them to next request only when correlation returns zero(not_found or default value)

Any suggestions Please

Answer (score 0):

If in case of failed correlation you want to supply a default value from the CSV file you can use [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage/) with [__jexl3() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) to check the variable value like:

[image]

So:

- If `${myVariable}` has value - second If Controller will be executed and the sampler will use correlated data
- If `${myVariable}` doesn't have value - first If Controller will be executed and the sampler will use the data from the CSV file

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks a lots!! :)